# Cannot unlink file in function

Tags: php

I want to delete a file via a variable by this function:

```php
$folder = 'upload/file/';
$save_path = $folder . $filename . '.' . 'file'; // <- Prop. name extension

function rndwnl($save_path)
{
    header('Content-type:  application/zip');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($save_path));
    readfile($save_path);
    ignore_user_abort(true);
    unlink($save_path);
}

if (isset($_GET['dwnlf'])) {
    rndwnl($save_path);
}
```

but this does not work.

But if I take unlink from the function it works

```php
<?php
...

unlink($save_path);

...
?>
```

How can I delete the file in the function? (after download)

(The filename changes of course again and again, therefore the var)

Comment: Have you tried with the full path rather than a relative path as you have shown here?

Comment: The php is in the html folder and in the html folder is the upload folder. Is this not already the full path?

Comment: A full (or "absolute") path would start from the root of your fileystem. But if the folder structure you've described is true then the relative path you've got looks ok, starting from the upload folder within the current folder the PHP is executing from. Also what does "does not work" actually mean? What error / warning do you get?

Comment: I don't get any errors, so I'm getting desperate. The file is simply not deleted

Comment: And the permissions are also correct (deleting outside the function works)

Comment: I think it won't delete an open file, and it thinks PHP is still trying to use it (because the output from readFile hasn't yet been sent to the browser until your script finishes executing). Maybe you need to have a cron job to sweep up these kinds of files later after they've been used or after a set time has expired. Are these files generated on-demand when the user requests the download, or at some prior time? If they're on-demand it might be posible to echo the content direct to the browser from the generation process, rather than saving to a file first.

Comment: I guess it might be possible that the file is somehow locked by the download process at the instance the `unlink` method is called. You could try putting a small `sleep` before calling `unlink`? By the full path perhaps try: `$folder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'upload/file/';`

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work either :/

Comment: I would like to delete the file via PHP, but I'm starting to think it would be easier to write a Python script that runs via cron and deletes files older than 10 minutes.

Comment: Or another PHP script which does that - why mix up the languages? It's usually easier to support an app which is all written in the same language, unless there's a really specific reason that one is better for a particular task. Deleting files doesn't really fall into that box...

Comment: @ADyson Unfortunately I have to save the file temporarily, otherwise I would have rewritten this s#it long ago

Comment: Why do you need to save it, specifically?

Comment: @ADyson I have already tried via include / Same problem....

Comment: What do you mean tried via include? When I said "another PHP script that which does that" I meant a PHP script triggered by cron. My point was only to say why write that in python when you already have a PHP-based ecosystem?

Comment: Data is written to the file via a Python (is only server-side it does not go via php unfortunately)

Comment: Alright well that's a valid reason, fair enough

Comment: Ok, I have a "better" (NOT GOOD) solution than an extra python script.... I just delete files older than 5m via cron. My solution ->  * * * * *  find /path/to/websrv/dir -type f -mmin +5  -exec rm -f {} +

Comment: true, bash can do the job just as easily if you don't have any complex logic about what should be deleted.